# Is passing a class into the .environmentObject modifier equivalent to creating a kind of Singleton?

Tags: swift, swiftui, singleton, environmentobject

Apple loves singletons but Singletons are considered bad practice and I am trying to remove them from an app I am converting to SwiftUI.

I have a singleton for App Store Purchases and Restores which is initialized when the app starts and contains a closure that will be called to update the database if a result comes from the App Store. The updates have nothing to do with the interface.

Something like this

```
let myAppStoreSingleton = MyAppStoreSingleton.sharedInstante
myAppStoreSingleton.initialize(runOnPurchase: { success() }, runOnFailure: { failure() })
```

As you know, the results will come async.

Now suppose that the result takes too long to arrive and the user thinks an error happened and moved to another screen. Does not matter because the singleton is there, on memory, and will run one of the closures when the result comes.

Now suppose I create a regular class and pass it on `MyApp.swift` as a `.environmentObject(MyAppStorePurchaseClass)`, like this:

```
let myAppStoreClass = MyAppStoreClass()
myAppStoreClass.initialize(runOnPurchase: { success() }, runOnFailure: { failure() })
```

Adding this to MyApp.swift...

```
var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
      .environmentObject(myAppStoreClass)
  }
}
```

Two questions:

1. It will produce the same effect as the singleton, right? It is sitting on memory and will run the closures `runOnPurchase` or `runOnFailure` when the results come, right?
2. will `myAppStoreClass` be available on either classes and views, by retrieving it with the @Environment wrapper?

Comment: Yes it’s like a singleton but you can only use an environment object in a view. And you access it using `@EnvironmentObject`

Comment: So, back to singletons again? I need the "singleton" stuff to be seen by other classes, basically. I don't like the idea of having to inject it back and forth from one thing to the other. I forget one and kaput!

Comment: You can use a class both as a singleton and an environment object of course

Comment: yes, but my idea was to get rid of the singleton... . Thanks anyway.

Comment: Use DI, You can access anything from anywhere and it will be the same instance

Comment: @loremipsum what are you talking about? Can you post an answer explaining? Remenber that I need to access the object from classes, not just views. thanks.

Comment: Dependency injection… I’ll try to make an example but if you google SwiftUI/Swift and Dependency Injection you’ll find several examples there are ven some packages out there (overkill). Basically create a “factory” of sorts , View > Manager > Service, the manager and/or service can be DI and accessed  from any other managers and services. It is the easiest way to “mock” stuff especially for previews where you don’t want to be making a ton of “real” calls to an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `.environmentObject()` is simply convenience to save you from having to pass an `ObservableObject` into every view until reaching the one it is needed in. So you can set `.environmentObject` at the top level and then access it down at the View you need it in. It's also possible to override an object on the way down but that is an advanced feature.

For your purposes it sounds like you might not need an object at all. Check out [`EnvironmentKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey) maybe you could use that? And there is an interesting built-in controller struct `AuthorizationController` that is defined as a key.

Comment: yes but the problem is that I need to access that object from classes. I can do that using singletons or I can do that using classes and passing it back and forth but this former stinks in my opinion.

Comment: just avoid classes then, this is Swift after all

Comment: Can you please add a code example? Sorry but your answer is too ethereal for me to grab.

Comment: Hard to make an example when I don't know what your `runOnPurchase` logic is. But essentially you should make a `.task` and then init your framework object and await a purchase (this logic can be refactored into a environment controller struct so you can mock it for testing) , then set the result on some state value, which you pass into/transform into child Views.